# XMLHttpRequest without cookies

Tags: javascript, cookies, greasemonkey

How can I send a request from javascript which would not use cookies? I want to do it from greasemonkey, so I don't care about same origin and can use both original `xmlhttprequest` or greamonkey's [GM_xmlhttpRequest](http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_xmlhttpRequest).

I need to fetch a page from the same website, but unauthentificated. Browser (Firefox) always sends all the cookies which FF have for that domain.

Background: I am working on a GM script which displays full size version of profile images. However the only way to know its URL, I must fetch the profile page for that user. This must be done unauthentificated, otherwise those users would be notified of me looking at their profile. Right now for development I use php on my server to fetch the profile page, but this is not scalable with the distribution of GM script for other users.

Comment: Clear All Cookie from domain and then send a request if possible .

Comment: I can't clear the cookies - the webpage must work for the browser user with cookies, just requests from greasemonkey script needs to be without cookies

Comment: http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/cookie-monster-for-xmlhttprequest/

Comment: @JaredFarrish I have read that article (quite old, lot of changes to FF since then), I tried the updated solution, but it seems I don't have access to `yourXMLHttpReq.channel` from greasemonkey script.

Comment: This is not possible with `GM_xmlhttpRequest`, but you could fork Greasemonkey's code and make your own version that had a "no cookie" option. ... Alternatively, Maybe run the script from a tab that is in private browsing mode?

Comment: @BrockAdams how can I open private tab via Greasemonkey?

Comment: You can't open the tab *via* Greasemonkey (although that's a possible feature request against `GM_openInTab()`).  You manually create a private tab and then open your target page (the one running the GM script) in that tab.  It will not share/see the cookies that are still present in non-private tabs.

Answer (score 7):

You can set the [mozAnon](https://github.com/greasemonkey/greasemonkey/commit/535d996c3266b99158fa0cd2729027551d8b4ebf) or [anonymous](https://github.com/arantius/greasemonkey/commit/02097ff595b1b3eb682f7f199b612101ed04f65a) flag on the request options to suppress sending/storing cookies.

Unfortunately these flags [aren't documented](https://github.com/greasemonkey/greasemonkey/issues/2396) in the [wiki](https://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_xmlhttpRequest) yet, but they seem to be [available since Version 3.8](https://github.com/greasemonkey/greasemonkey/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aclosed%20milestone%3A3.8)beta3 (April 18, 2016).

```
GM_xmlhttpRequest({
   method: 'GET',
   url: url,
   anonymous: true, // remove original cookies
   headers: {
      cookie: 'whatever' // add custom cookies if necessary
   },
   onload: function(res) {
      // optionally parse the reponse cookies which are otherwise lost
      const cookieRegex = /^Set-Cookie: (.*)$/gm;
      const cookies = [];
      while (cookieRegex.exec(res.responseHeaders)) {
         cookies.push(RegExp.$1);
      }
      console.log(cookies);
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I also discovered the same bug number last week, but hadn't time yet to test it.